# SQLAlchemy 1.4 overiding system value

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I currently am using SQL Alchemy Core specifically with the SQL Expression Language.
I have a table that is currently using the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` parameter.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
col1 VARCHAR(100),col2 VARCHAR(100));
```

Everytime I try insert in the table, i'm getting the error:

```
DETAIL:  Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
HINT:  Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
```

I know that if I just to use postgres I could:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id,col1,col2) OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE 
VALUES (%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
```

But how would do this using the sql expression language that sqlalchemy provides?
I am currently upserting like this:

```
insert_stmt = postgresql.insert(target).values(vals)
primary_keys = [key.name for key in inspect(target).primary_key]

stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=primary_keys)
conn.execute(stmt)
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `overriding system value` to begin with. You should simply exclude the `id` column from the insert.

Comment: but when I do an upsert into the table, and the `ON CONFLICT` is on the id, I get the error I mentioned above, since the id column is GENERATED AS IDENTITY

Comment: Using `on conflict()` on a generated ID doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I have been not to use `SERIAL` anymore, so I started using `GENERATED`.  In my example, I am trying to add new rows to the target table from staging table, so I would use `on conflict()` to ignore the ids that already exist in the target table and insert the new ones.

Comment: You should use `on conflict()` on the columns that make your rows unique with regards to your business rules. The artificial generated primary key shouldn't be used for that.

Comment: the column `id` is unique in that regards, are you saying I should remove the generated primary key since I always have a staging table that is inserting into the target table?  Could I continue using this method, but just remove the generated primary key?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` to use fixed IDs in my tests.
As far as I can see, SQLAlchemy doesn't support this at the moment.

I hacked it in this way:

```py
@compiles(Insert)
def set_inserts_overriding_system_value(the_insert, compiler, **kw):
    text = compiler.visit_insert(the_insert, **kw)
    text = text.replace(") VALUES (", ") OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE VALUES (")
    return text
```

You can probably create some weird tables or insert queries on purpose, that will be messed up by this text replace. But it won't ever happen by accident.